# How to use React form input event handler?

Tags: reactjs

I am fetching country code API, storing it in select field as an option. I have one select field where user can select country and in another input box country calling code will display automatically.

I am trying to select country value in input box and handleSelectCountry will select country and handleInputChange will target the country code and value will select automatically.

How I can achieve that?

```
     componentDidMount() {
        fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
            console.warn(result);
            this.setState({ countries: result });
            console.log("i am in console");
          });
      }


   state ={
       name:''
   }
   handleSelectCountry= (event) =>{
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const myCountry = (event.target.value);
    this.setState = ({value: event.target.value});
    const selectedCountry = event.target.value;
   }
   handleInputChange = (event) =>{
       console.log(event.target.value);
       const myCountryCode = event.target.value;
       this.setState = ({value: event.target.value});
   }
    render (){
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                <div className="input-group Form-main">
                  <select onChange={this.handleCountrySelectChange}>
                    {this.state.countries.map(country => (
                    <option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
                    {country.name}
                    </option>
            ))}
          </select>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>

<br />
             <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                <div className="input-group Form-main">
                  <input type="text" 
                   placeholder = " Auto Select" 
                   required="required" 
                   onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            {/* ----Form ends */}
       </div>
     );
    
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `countries` to your initial state:

```
state = {
  name: '',
  countries: [],
}
```

Instead of

```
this.setState = ({value: event.target.value});
```

call method setState, and change key `value` to `name`

```
this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
```

`onChange` should looks like

```
<select onChange={event => this.handleSelectCountry(event)}>
```

And add `value` param to your input

```
<input type="text"
  placeholder=" Auto Select"
  required="required"
  onChange={event => this.handleInputChange(event)}
  value={this.state.name}
/>
```

Final result:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      console.warn(result);
      this.setState({ countries: result });
      console.log("i am in console");
    });
}
state = {
  name: '',
  countries: [],
}
handleSelectCountry = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);
  const myCountry = (event.target.value);
  this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
  const selectedCountry = event.target.value;
}
handleInputChange = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.value);
  const myCountryCode = event.target.value;
  this.setState({ name: event.target.value });
}
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
          <div className="input-group Form-main">
            <select onChange={event => this.handleSelectCountry(event)}>
              {this.state.countries.map(country => (
                <option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
                  {country.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
          <div className="input-group Form-main">
            <input type="text"
              placeholder=" Auto Select"
              required="required"
              onChange={event => this.handleInputChange(event)}
              value={this.state.name}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* ----Form ends */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Here Input box is showing country Name . But If I want to get country Calling code automatically then in input box then Do I need add value = { this.state.countryCallingCode} ?

Comment: `<option key={country.name} value={country.callingCodes[0]}>`